# This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled (internal generated filenames are not absolute)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda

Just started a Data Analysis course with Pandas and Python and we are using Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook, I was following the steps to install everything and it all seemed OK but when I try to run Jupyter Notebook I get this:

```
This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled
(internal generated filenames are not absolute).
This may make the debugger miss breakpoints.
```

(My knoweledge on programming in general is limited, I only know of basic C, Java and Python from my first year of University, also English is not my first language so I apologize in advance if I need to ask for clarification)

I am on a Windows 10 computer, I ran the conda info command and this is the information I got on conda and python on the enviroment I am using:

```
conda version: 23.5.0
conda-build version: 3.24.0
python version: 3.10.9.final.0
```

The most similar inquiry I found on this was solved by deactivating all enviroments (even the base one) and then activating only the necessary enviroment. I tried that but I still get the same error. I also tried updating everything and deleting everything and starting from scratch. Still same error.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure what causes those errors but you night need to try creating an Anacoda environment with an earlier Python version. See the documentation [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/navigator/tutorials/create-python35-environment/)

Comment: @YannisP. I tried that but now I get a ton of kernel errors on Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Not sure anyone at SO can help you as it is very difficult to see the errors. Perhaps you better install everything from scratch.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Let aside the comment on specificity you can try either Google Colab or a similar platform from ia JetBrains, for running Jupyter notebooks online and saving from some of the configuration hassle.

Comment: @YannisP. Thank you for your help, I will try alternatives. Thanks again.